# Replacing the title attribute in imgbox

Tags: javascript, html

Using the most recent build of [imgbox](http://jqueryglobe.com/article/imgbox), encountering the same problem I had with LightBox2; mainly, the 'title' attribute. It makes a caption, but html likes to make a hovertext over the image link.

Like so:

```
  <a id="example1-1" href="./painting/everythingieverwanted/everythingieverwanted.jpg" title="Lorem <a href=''> ipsum</a> dolor sit amet">
```

I went in and tried to manually switch all instances of 'title' in jquery.imgbox.js to 'imagecaption', and renamed my attributes accordingly, so:

```
  <a id="example1-1" href="./painting/everythingieverwanted/everythingieverwanted.jpg" imagecaption="Lorem <a href=''> ipsum</a> dolor sit amet">
```

but that didn't work. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like imgBox comes with a second .jss file that needs to be altered that I didn't notice at first: jquery.imgbox.pack.js

Basically I went through and replaced all "title" attributes with "imgboxcaption" in both

jquery.imgbox.pack.js
and
jquery.imgbox.js
and
imgbox.css

then, when writing it out, this works:

```
<a id="popup" href="./painting/everythingieverwanted/everythingieverwanted.jpg" imgboxcaption="Lorem <a href=''>Ipsum</a>"><img src="./painting/everythingieverwanted/redsuitBOX.jpg" /></a>
```

No html hover because of the title tag, and the caption is there.

Note that the titleh attribute does not need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

So the reason you're getting hell is because your tags are CRAZY malformed:

```
<a id="example1-1" href="./painting/everythingieverwanted/everythingieverwanted.jpg" imagecaption="Lorem <a href=''>
```

should be

```
<a id="example1-1" href="./painting/everythingieverwanted/everythingieverwanted.jpg" imagecaption="Lorem Ipsum">
```

You should not have *any* HTML in the value you're setting for the caption. It just turns out bad. Also, you cannot nest `<a>` tags. Browsers freak out badly when you do.

If you just want to store a value with the link, use the HTML5 data attributes:

```
<a id="example1-1" href="./painting/everythingieverwanted/everythingieverwanted.jpg" data-caption="Lorem Ipsum">
```

Comment: Nested <a> tags within the title tag worked just fine with Lightbox & Slimbox2.

Comment: Nested `<a>` tags are a violation of the HTML spec. Many browsers WILL display them improperly, and they WILL create problems.